# How to login to a page using mongoDB post request isnt recognized?

Tags: node.js, ejs

Hi there im having difficulty with my post request for login,

I've managed to get register working and i redirect it to login so i can attempt, the account registered goes onto mongodb correctly, from some testing with multiple logs, turns out the post for login isnt effecting it, and it simply redirects again to login, unsure how that is

heres what i got

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
type: String,
required: true
},
email: {
type: String,
required: true
},
password: {
type: String,
required: true
}
 })

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema)
```

This is for where im storing the users info for the login page

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<form action="/login" method="GET">
<div>
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="name" id="name" name="name" required>
</div>
<div>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
</div>
<div>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
</div>
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
<a href="/">Register a User</a>
```

Register is the same as this only with the href relating to this login page

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const users = require('../models/users')
const book = require('../models/book')

router.get('/home', async (req, res) => {
let books
try {
books = await book.find().sort({ createdAt: 'desc' }).limit(10).exec()
} catch {
books = []
}
res.render('home.ejs', { books: books })
})



//Login user
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render('index.ejs')

}) 


router.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
res.render('login')

})

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
console.log("HI")
try{  
const valid=await users.findOne({name:req.body.name})
if (valid.password===req.body.password){
  res.render('home')

}
else{
  console.log("HI")
  res.send("Incorrect Password Try again?")
  res.render('home')
}
}catch{
console.log("HI")
res.render('home')
}
})


//Register and upload to DB 
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

const user = ({
name: req.body.name,
email: req.body.email,
password: req.body.password,


})
await users.insertMany([user])

res.redirect('/')
})




module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form you have mentioned method as "GET" . It is a post request so method should be "POST".

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
```

Comment: thanks there it is!, was wonder what was going on for a while searching the wrong places!